# PostgreSQL (EnterpriseDB) on a Mac with OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, postgresql

I recently installed PostgresSQL on my laptop and have a weird problem with the shell/terminal. I can create a database and table with pgAdmin III, but entering commands in the terminal doesn't accomplish anything.

One weird thing is that when I double click on the PostgreSQL shell icon, it opens APPLE's terminal.

I just discovered that PostgreSQL is already installed on Mac's, apparently as part of the serve. If I understand correctly, you still have to install it independently if you want to work with it database (I think).

Anyway, I'm thoroughly confused.  I'm not sure if I need to tinker with some files to "separate" the PostgreSQL and Apple terminals or if I need to uninstall PostgreSQL. And if I uninstall it, how do I do it without installing the PostgreSQL files associated with Apple's server.

Then again, I don't really use Apple's serve - unless it serves some function I'm not aware of.

I'm snowed. In summary, if you've installed PostgreSQL EnterpriseDB on a Mac running OS X El Capitan and had similar problems, how did you fix them?

Comment: Postgres doesn't have a "terminal". It has a command line client, that you start from _within_ a terminal. So there is nothing to "separate". Also: what exactly does "*doesn't accomplish anything*" mean? What is the error message you get? What are the exact commands you have entered in the `psql` client?

Comment: When I double click on the PostgreSQL icon, an icon appears on my taskbar. It looks like a little monitor with a white frame. When I click on the icon, another monitor without a white frame appears, with the following text: Last login: Tue Oct 27 16:09:53 on ttys000
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/scripts/runpsql.sh; exit
Davids-MacBook-Pro-2:~ davidblomstrom$ /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/scripts/runpsql.sh; exit
Server [localhost]:

Comment: I was following some suggestions the other day, pasting in scripts that were supposed to create databases, tables, alter tables, etc. I don't recall any error messages; the problem was that nothing happened. I wasn't able to create or alter anything. Also, the shells, terminals, monitors or whatever you call them multiply until I have as many as a dozen. Is that normal when using PostgreSQL on a Mac? It seems odd to me. Oh, yes - I sometimes pasted the same command in two different terminals/clients and got two different results.

Comment: No offense, but you first need to learn the basics on how to use the command line on a computer. Typically you open a terminal type `psql` to start the SQL client and then enter the commands there. You don't "double click" each time you enter a command - you keep the terminal open. But unless you provide us with the specific commands you have problems with, we can't help you. But if you are not experienced using the command line (with Postgres and a computer in general), then why don't you stick with pgAdmin or another GUI tool?

Comment: Actually, that's my preference. I would prefer to avoid using the command-line client altogether. However, some people who were helping me on a listserve insisted that I use the terminal. They gave me a series of commands, which I pasted in. When I clicked ENTER, there were no error messages - but nothing happened, either; in other words, the commands never created new tables.

Comment: And why didn't you run those statements in pgAdmin (or any other GUI client)? For a SQL statement it doesn't matter _where_ you run it. But again: without seeing what you actually did, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: In summary, I'd be happy to ignore the command-line client altogether. I was just concerned that some of the things that seemed weird to me might be evidence of a bad installation. I don't think I ever double-clicked when entering a command. I just pasted in the command and hit ENTER/RETURN. All of a sudden I had a dozen terminals open. Again, I'm happy to ignore the terminal altogether if I can find a place where I can get advice on using pgAdmin instead.

Comment: That sounds more like a problem with the MacOS terminal application rather than `psql` or Postgres.

Comment: OK, let me try a different approach. Let's just forget the shell/terminal/command-line completely, as I wanted to do from the beginning. Is it possible to create a table by pasting a block of code into pgAdmin III? If so could you give me the code for a simple table and tell me where to paste it? I've learned how to create a table piece by piece with a tutorial @ http://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/create-table.php

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think the EDB installer must've added a Dock shortcut to launch a terminal with psql, and that's the source of the confusion here, since it makes it seem like `psql` is an application, not a commandline program. I can't explain how the multiplying terminals happened, but I don't have a Mac to test on (and Apple's policies prevent me from running a VM to test like I would any other operating system).

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom Use the PgAdmin SQL editor / query tool. http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/query.html . It supports everything psql does, except backslash-commands like `\copy`. BTW, you can completely ignore the PostgreSQL instance installed as part of `Server.app`, it's isolated in newer OS X versions and shouldn't affect anything at all.

Comment: Got it; thx. On the positive side, I managed to make my first table with pgAdmin III and was amazed at how easy it was to make a database connection and simple query. It took me far longer to do that with MySQL years ago. ;)